# set REPLY-TO in email pony ruby

Tags: ruby, sinatra, pony

we have our `API` built in Ruby with `Sinatra` gem. and using `Pony` for sending emails. I want to set parameter `reply-to`. i have tried every possibility, even the way Pony gem docs say but its not working at all..

Our mailer code is

```
require 'logjam'
require 'pony'

module Evercam
  module Mailers
    class Mailer
      LogJam.apply(self, "actors")

      @@templates = {}

      def initialize(inputs)
        @inputs = inputs
      end

      def erb(name)
        ERB.new(template(name)).result(binding)
      end

      private

      def template(name)
        @@templates[name] ||= File.read(
          File.expand_path(File.join('.', name))
        )
      end

      def method_missing(name)
        if @inputs.keys.include?(name)
          @inputs[name]
        end
      end

      def self.method_missing(name, *inputs)
        if self.method_defined?(name) && inputs[0]
          begin
            opts = self.new(inputs[0]).send(name)
            mail = Evercam::Config[:mail].merge(opts)
            Pony.mail(mail)
          rescue Exception => e
            log.warn(e)
          end
        end
      end

    end
  end
end

require_relative 'mailer'

module Evercam
  module Mailers
    class UserMailer < Mailer

      def confirm
        {
          to: user.email,
          subject: 'Evercam Confirmation',
          html_body: erb('templates/emails/user/confirm.html.erb'),
          body: erb('templates/emails/user/confirm.txt')
        }
      end

      def share
        {
          to: email,
          subject: "#{user.fullname} has shared a camera with you",
          html_body: erb('templates/emails/user/camera_shared_notification.html.erb'),
          attachments: attachments,
          reply_to: sharer
        }
      end

      def share_request
        {
          to: email,
          subject: "#{user.fullname} has shared a camera with you",
          html_body: erb('templates/emails/user/sign_up_to_share_email.html.erb'),
          attachments: attachments,
          reply_to: sharer
        }
      end

      def interested
        {
          to: 'signups@evercam.io',
          subject: 'Signup on evercam.io',
          body: erb('templates/emails/user/interested.txt')
        }
      end

      def app_idea
        {
          to: 'garrett@evercam.io',
          subject: 'Marketplace idea on evercam.io',
          body: erb('templates/emails/user/app_idea.txt')
        }
      end

      def create_success
        {
          to: archive.user.email,
          subject: "Archive #{archive.title} is ready.",
          html_body: erb('templates/emails/user/archive_create_completed.html.erb'),
          attachments: attachments
        }
      end

      def create_fail
        {
          to: archive.user.email,
          subject: "Archive #{archive.title} failed.",
          html_body: erb('archive_creation_failed.html.erb'),
          attachments: attachments
        }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

the reply_to in `share` and in `share_request` isn't working at all.. any help will be appreciated. thanks

Comment: trigger an external script which can do the job for you from the controller.

Comment: It would be a good idea to add the versions of Pony gem and Mail gem from the `Gemfile.lock` file that your app uses.

Comment: I take it that you've tried a simpler case, using Pony in a stand-alone program, with a hard-coded reply-to parameter?  If not, that would be a good next step, I think.  (Also: perhaps I'm just not seeing it, but where does `share` come from in the above code?)

Comment: I mean `sharer` not `share`...

Answer (score 1):

The question seems old, but I stumbled upon it when I was asking myself the same question.
I finally went back to the pony git page and found the answer in the [documentation](https://github.com/benprew/pony#list-of-options).

### List Of Options

You can get a list of options from Pony directly:

```
Pony.permissable_options
```

## Options passed pretty much directly to Mail

- attachments # see Attachments section
- bcc
- body # the plain text body
- body_part_header # see Custom headers section
- cc
- charset # In case you need to send in utf-8 or similar
- content_type
- from
- headers # see Custom headers section
- html_body # for sending html-formatted email
- html_body_part_header # see Custom headers section
- message_id
- **reply_to**  *#This one seems to be the one we're looking for. Not yet tested.*
- sender  # Sets "envelope from" (and the Sender header)
- smtp_envelope_to
- subject
- text_part_charset # for multipart messages, set the charset of the text part
- to